# Ignore file already tracked in git

Tags: git

I have the following contents in my `.gitignore` file

```
**/*.txt
**/*.out
**/*.DS_store
**/*.exe
**/a.out
```

However, every time I compile my **c++** files I get `a.out` files as executable and I still get file as modified when I do `git status`. I'll be thankful if someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have accidentally added the file to the index.
You can remove it from the index using:

```
git rm --cached a.out
```

Git will no longer track this file.

From the manual:

> ```
> --cached
> ```
>
> Use this option to unstage and remove paths only from the index. Working tree files, whether modified or not, will be left alone.

Comment: Thank you. Though this has been marked as duplicate. +1 :)